# Deadlocks in mysql database (Percona Server for mysql 5.7.22-22-1.trusty)

Tags: mysql, deadlock, percona

We have a problem with deadlocks in mysql database (Percona Server for mysql 5.7.22-22-1.trusty).
Every 24 hours our mysql stops responding. The process is still running but we can't create new connections.
After analysis of threads we saw that there are cycles in locks.
Do you have any idea what can we do to solve our problem?

Enviroment

```
Linux version 3.13.0-151-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-034) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) ) #201-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 14:22:13 UTC 2018
MemTotal: 528281684 kB
cpu: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 v3 @ 2.60GHz

jupyther (kvm, qemu)
MemTotal: 154745476 kB
```

GDB session:

```
(gdb) thread 1634
[Switching to thread 1634 (Thread 0x7fe9bacdb700 (LWP 124547))]
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
135     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007feb62d3767f in _L_lock_1081 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2cba198) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
#3  0x000000000079d77d in Global_THD_manager::do_for_all_thd_copy(Do_THD_Impl*) ()
#4  0x0000000000cedba0 in calc_sum_of_all_status(system_status_var*) ()
#5  0x0000000000ca3fbc in dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) ()
#6  0x0000000000ca5097 in do_command(THD*) ()
#7  0x0000000000d6a9d0 in handle_connection ()
#8  0x0000000000ede1e4 in pfs_spawn_thread ()
#9  0x00007feb62d35184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fe9bacdb700) at pthread_create.c:312
#10 0x00007feb6224203d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb) up 2
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x2cba198) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
134     ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print mutex.__data.__owner
$9 = 142327
(gdb) thread find 142327
Thread 1611 has target id 'Thread 0x7fe9bb762700 (LWP 142327)'
(gdb) thread 1611
[Switching to thread 1611 (Thread 0x7fe9bb762700 (LWP 142327))]
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
135     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007feb62d3767f in _L_lock_1081 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fe76142fbe8) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
#3  0x0000000000cfecac in Fill_process_list::operator()(THD*) ()
#4  0x000000000079d8dd in Global_THD_manager::do_for_all_thd_copy(Do_THD_Impl*) ()
#5  0x0000000000ce61bc in fill_schema_processlist(THD*, TABLE_LIST*, Item*) ()
#6  0x0000000000ce628c in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000cf914c in get_schema_tables_result(JOIN*, enum_schema_table_state) ()
#8  0x0000000000cdc0ad in JOIN::prepare_result() ()
#9  0x0000000000c6cce0 in JOIN::exec() ()
#10 0x0000000000cdc9fd in handle_query(THD*, LEX*, Query_result*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#11 0x000000000075cf43 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000c9f8f6 in mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool) ()
#13 0x0000000000ca2afd in mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*) ()
#14 0x0000000000ca36bd in dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) ()
#15 0x0000000000ca5097 in do_command(THD*) ()
#16 0x0000000000d6a9d0 in handle_connection ()
#17 0x0000000000ede1e4 in pfs_spawn_thread ()
#18 0x00007feb62d35184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fe9bb762700) at pthread_create.c:312
#19 0x00007feb6224203d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb) up 2
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x7fe76142fbe8) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
134     ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print mutex.__data.__owner
$10 = 109111
(gdb) thread find 109111
Thread 1648 has target id 'Thread 0x7fe9bbb98700 (LWP 109111)'
(gdb) thread 1648
[Switching to thread 1648 (Thread 0x7fe9bbb98700 (LWP 109111))]
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
135     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007feb62d37649 in _L_lock_909 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007feb62d37470 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x1d7ebe8 <mysql_bin_log+8>) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:79
#3  0x0000000000d3021f in PolyLock_lock_log::rdlock() ()
#4  0x0000000000c133b5 in sys_var::value_ptr(THD*, THD*, enum_var_type, st_mysql_lex_string*) ()
#5  0x0000000000ceda2c in get_one_variable_ext(THD*, THD*, st_mysql_show_var const*, enum_var_type, enum_mysql_show_type, system_status_var*, charset_info_st const**, char*, unsigned long*) ()
#6  0x0000000000f08869 in System_variable::init(THD*, st_mysql_show_var const*, enum_var_type) ()
#7  0x0000000000f08e75 in PFS_system_variable_cache::do_materialize_all(THD*) ()
#8  0x0000000000f34b0a in table_session_variables::rnd_init(bool) ()
#9  0x0000000000edca2c in ha_perfschema::rnd_init(bool) ()
#10 0x0000000000807722 in handler::ha_rnd_init(bool) ()
#11 0x0000000000c04f34 in init_read_record(READ_RECORD*, THD*, TABLE*, QEP_TAB*, int, bool, bool) ()
#12 0x0000000000c705be in join_init_read_record(QEP_TAB*) ()
#13 0x0000000000c73f8b in sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) ()
#14 0x0000000000c6ce97 in JOIN::exec() ()
#15 0x0000000000c68c14 in TABLE_LIST::materialize_derived(THD*) ()
#16 0x0000000000c6d8bf in join_materialize_derived(QEP_TAB*) ()
#17 0x0000000000c6d3b2 in QEP_TAB::prepare_scan() ()
#18 0x0000000000c73eb0 in sub_select(JOIN*, QEP_TAB*, bool) ()
#19 0x0000000000c6ce97 in JOIN::exec() ()
#20 0x0000000000cdc9fd in handle_query(THD*, LEX*, Query_result*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) ()
#21 0x000000000075cf43 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000c9f8f6 in mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool) ()
#23 0x0000000000ca2afd in mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*) ()
#24 0x0000000000ca36bd in dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) ()
#25 0x0000000000ca5097 in do_command(THD*) ()
#26 0x0000000000d6a9d0 in handle_connection ()
#27 0x0000000000ede1e4 in pfs_spawn_thread ()
#28 0x00007feb62d35184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fe9bbb98700) at pthread_create.c:312
#29 0x00007feb6224203d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb) up 2
#2  0x00007feb62d37470 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x1d7ebe8 <mysql_bin_log+8>) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:79
79      ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) print mutex.__data.__owner
$11 = 63889
(gdb) thread find 63889
Thread 1808 has target id 'Thread 0x7fea780f5700 (LWP 63889)'
(gdb) thread 1808
[Switching to thread 1808 (Thread 0x7fea780f5700 (LWP 63889))]
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
135     ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007feb62d3767f in _L_lock_1081 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x1d37c80 <LOCK_status>) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
#3  0x0000000000e5b098 in MYSQL_BIN_LOG::publish_coordinates_for_global_status() const ()
#4  0x0000000000e6147e in MYSQL_BIN_LOG::ordered_commit(THD*, bool, bool) ()
#5  0x0000000000e64902 in MYSQL_BIN_LOG::commit(THD*, bool) ()
#6  0x00000000008005e1 in ha_commit_trans(THD*, bool, bool) ()
#7  0x0000000000d4b7be in trans_commit_stmt(THD*) ()
#8  0x0000000000c9b6ea in mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool) ()
#9  0x0000000000ca2afd in mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*) ()
#10 0x0000000000ca36bd in dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command) ()
#11 0x0000000000ca5097 in do_command(THD*) ()
#12 0x0000000000d6a9d0 in handle_connection ()
#13 0x0000000000ede1e4 in pfs_spawn_thread ()
#14 0x00007feb62d35184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fea780f5700) at pthread_create.c:312
#15 0x00007feb6224203d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
(gdb) up 2
#2  0x00007feb62d375f8 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x1d37c80 <LOCK_status>) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
134     ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)  print mutex.__data.__owner
$12 = 124547
(gdb) thread find 124547
Thread 1634 has target id 'Thread 0x7fe9bacdb700 (LWP 124547)'
```

Comment: _Disclosure: I am from Percona_
We think possibly there is an environment problem here. If you use gdb, then make sure you can hook pthread and make sure to run the debug version of the Percona package build. This way you can get debug symbols in the stack trace. Then reproduce the issue and see if it is still happening? 

If you post to percona.com/forums I probably have a better chance of getting you the right help. That is entirely up to you though. Either way, if there's an answer we can update this post here.

Comment: @Milena Kapciak Please post text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%' ; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; since threads are involved in your information provided.

Comment: Hey, accordig to information posted on percona task: https://jira.percona.com/browse/PS-4590 we made downgrade to version  5.7.17-11-1. Since downgrade our database works stable.

Comment: @MilenaKapciak  Great news about being stable.  For suggestions to improve performance, please post text results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%thread%' ; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%thread%'; .